# The Drop-down content of AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, themes, autocompletetextview

The Drop-down content of `AutoCompleteTextView` is the white word. But it can not be seen clear. How to deal with this？

This is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this,android.R.layout.browser_link_context_header, info_array);
```

The font still can not be seen clear. Then I change the code like this: `myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dropdown_tv);`

It still can not see the font. Please help me. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to keep whatever theme you have for the app as it is, and only change the theme in this activity that have the `AutoCompleteTextView` to `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);`

here some guy solved it by overriding `Widget.AutoCompleteTextView` theme check [didldum](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237#c8) answer here it might help you:

***[Quoted from code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237#c8)***

```
1. use an extended theme in your manifest:
...
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Workaround" ... >
...

2. create the new theme (res/values/themes.xml) which uses fixed styles:
...
    <style name="Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Workaround" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewLight</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.DropDownItemLight</item>
    </style>
...

3. create the styles (res/values/styles.xml) which fix the color:
...
    <style name="AutoCompleteTextViewLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.DropDownItemLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    </style>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem **But** I was use android Support Library. and `Theme.AppCompat.Light` Theme.

My problem was happen only with `android 2.3` devices.

I had solve problem by change layout of drop down To :

```
R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item
```